# How can I route controllers using MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I got two controllers in a VS 2015 web app the I define a regular menu using asp tag helpers to call each view, one of the options in that menu uses another control however is always calling the same controller, I am not sure if something changes now with MVC 6. 
I was using the following routes:

```
            config.MapRoute(
            name: "Event",
            template: "Event/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Event", action = "Index" }
                );

            config.MapRoute(
            name: "App",
            template: "App/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new {controller="App",action="Index"}
                );
```

Comment: The problem I had all the time and I am going to call myself "stupid" it was when calling controllers from the view I was using asp-controllers and I did not realize there was a "s" the correct way is without it. Gonna keep this just in case someone could make the same mistake, I don't think so but just in case.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've found, by default, one has to use attributes to setup routing in MVC 6. There is a shim (see http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/) to allow the compatibility with the method you are attempting.

This page (http://www.ryadel.com/en/custom-routing-method-names-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6/) is a little misleading because it makes it sound like there is a choice between MapRoute and/or using attributes. Regardless, it has some good examples.

Summary: Delete all calls to MapRoute and use attributes in your controllers.